# Почему выходит пустой массив? Javascript

Tags: javascript, массивы

Изучаю и практикуюсь на задачнике по Javascript.

Задание №4 такое:  Найдите все года от 1 до 2019, сумма цифр которых равна 13. Для этого используйте вспомогательную функцию из предыдущей задачи.

Не пойму почему пустой массив выходит. Вроде задание простое, а видимо, по не знанию, как точно работает Javascript, не могу понять, что не так. Подскажите пожалуйста =)

```
// Task 3
function getDigits(num) {
    return String(num).split("");
}


function getDigitsSum(num) {
    var sum= 0;
    for (i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
        sum += Number(num[i]);
    }
    return getDigitsSum(getDigits(num));
}

function summa(n){
    return getDigitsSum(getDigits(n));
}



// Task 4
var arrYear = [];

function yearSum(){
    for(i=1; i<=2019; i++){

        if (summa[i] == 13){
        arrYear.push(i);
        }
    }
    return arrYear;
}
console.log(arrYear);
```

Comment: а почему он должен быть не пустой?

Comment: Ну я пытаюсь push добавить в пустой архив все числа которые в сумме дают 13. Ошибку со скобками заметил только. Но всё равно не выходит запись чисел в новый массив.

Comment: ну ок. добавляешь ты в функции. а вызов её **где?**

Comment: Это конечно замечательно, что вы задаёте наводящие вопросы) Но будучи новичком в этом, сложно понимать. Я вывел функцию сразу после её написания, но мой массив по прежнему пуст =) Чего я не вижу?)

Comment: еще один вопрос: вот вы написали функции (если это сделали вы, конечно). Что с ними обычно делают? И для чего? Как они работают?

Comment: Вызывают в нужном месте по надобности) Но если я правильно понимаю, я могу вызвать только одну функцию yearSum(); а она уже потащит остальные. Или мне перед этим остальные тоже нужно вызывать?)

Comment: `я могу вызвать только одну функцию yearSum();.` - так, ок. Где её вызов?

Comment: В общем то я пробовал вывести функцию сразу после написания, но всё равно получал пустой массив. Я разобрался в проблеме. В функции getDigitsSum(num) - return модифицировал , чтобы не дописывать функцию summa. Забыл вернуть изначальное положение. В итоге из-за неправильного return'a вся канитель. А так спасибо. Я так полагаю функцию надо вызывать, без меня она не вызовется)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
function getDigits(num) {
  return String(num).split("");
}


function getDigitsSum(num) {
  var sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < num.length; i++) { //Не просто i = 0, а let i = 0. У меня при первом запуске браузер лёг)
    sum += +num[i];
  }

  return sum;
}

function summa(n) {
  return getDigitsSum(getDigits(n));
}



// Task 4
var arrYear = [];

function yearSum() {
  for (let i = 1; i <= 2019; i++) { //Тоже самое let i

    if (summa(i) == 13) { // summa(i) (круглые скобки), а не квадратные
      arrYear.push(i);
    }
  }
  return arrYear;
}
console.log(yearSum()); // Запускаем функцию, вы же писали "console.log(arrYear);
```

Comment: Спасибо. Я сам запутался в return'e , где функция getDigitalsSum. Отсюда основная проблема. У меня кстати перебор цикла for работал без let и var. Объясните пожалуйста почему именно let и можно ли использовать var вместо него?  А так у меня в конце было yearSum(); и
console.log(arrYear); , что вроде тоже правильно, ну... или по крайней мере работает)

Comment: @Павел, Можно и `var`, просто по новым стандарт принятно писать `let`)

Comment: Спасибо) Буду постепенно привыкать к стандартам) Пока главное понимать и писать работающий код, а там с практикой и остальное подтянется) Надеюсь =)

Comment: Минус зв ответ...  Разница между ***Let && Var*** не в том, что принято или не принято, а в том что ***Let***  переменная локальная, даже для циклов, чего не скажешь о ***var***

Comment: @Air, если на то пошло, то разница не только в этом. Если обратиться к переменной var до её объявления - выведет `underfined`. Если `let` - будет ошибка. Просто конкретно в циклах нет особой разницы что использовать, если мы не вешаем обработчики и т.п.. Он спросил можно ли писать `var`, ответ - можно